# Java 8 - put light element in a target Map from an other Map

Tags: java, java-8

**My code is:**

```
Map<String, Application> applications = new HashMap<>();

// add elements to applications here ...

applications.forEach((key, app) -> { System.out.println(key + " " + app.getHomeUrl()); });

Map<String, String> apps = new HashMap<>();
applications.forEach((key, app) -> { apps.put(key, app.getHomeUrl()); });
metrics.setApplications(apps);
```

But I looking for how to use a simple filter and not use a toporary Map (apps)?

**Console:**

```
xxxx https://xxxx.github.io/xxxx.io
githubapi null
google http://www.google.fr
demo null
yyyy https://yyyy.github.io/yyyy.io
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to avoid creating the `apps` `Map`? What would you use instead of that?

Comment: @Eran, yes, I want to avoid creating the temporary map apps. My code works, it's just to make cleaner and use the possibilities of java 8.

Comment: So what would you create instead of that Map? Or do you want just to eliminate the local variable `apps`, and pass the Map directly to your `setApplications()` method (as in Naman's answer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to avoid creating the `apps` variable would be

```
metrics.setApplications(applications.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().getHomeUrl() != null) // filter out entries with null homeUrl
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getHomeUrl())));
```

where the `toMap` is collecting the `key` from the `applications` Map and the value is mapped to the `homeUrl` while collecting the respective entries.

Comment: It does create the Map. I'm not sure the OP wanted to avoid just the local variable.

Comment: @Eran Agreed. Hence the deliberate use of *avoid creating the `apps` variable* in the answer.

Comment: @Naman, There is a problem in the response in the case where `applications[x] .homeUrl` is `null`

Comment: @Naman, I edit the poste with a `forEach` and a `System.out.println`. You can read a sample of data

Comment: @sgrillon are you willing to filter the entries for `null` URLs?

Comment: @Naman, yes I can filter the entries for `null`. With my code I did not need filter to do it, it's strange.